# How do I make rsync work over the serial port?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, rsync, putty

I am using a Raspberry Pi zero that runs on Rasbpian, and am connecting it with a computer, through a transceiver. I use minicom on the Raspberry Pi and Putty on the laptop to second documents.

I wrote some code that automatically generates files in a folder, and want to send those files through serial to my laptop the moment they are generated. I've heard that I can use rsync for this, but only read about people using it with SSH. One friend advised using piping, but I am new to this, so did not understand how to use piping with rsync.

Comment: if your serial communication is already supporting this communication you can just `cat` the files to the port. Not pretty I know, but it's serial connection, what can you do :D
Btw, can't you use ethernet?